# Is the right click context menu still available for Google Backup and Sync on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, google-drive

I often used the context menu in Windows Explorer (Windows 7) by right clicking on a file and sharing the file via Google Drive. Now that Google Drive has been replaced by Backup and Sync, I no longer get Google Drive options in the context menu when I right click (as of March 12 2018). In my Backup and Sync preferences, I have "Show file sync status icons and right click menu" enabled but still see no options on right click in Windows Explorer. Are these options no longer available or can I activate them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this problem using a method I found on [this thread on Google product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/4ToBj1nHiJc).

Register the context menu DLL manually by running Command Prompt in administrator mode and call:

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\contextmenu64.dll"
```

Then restart Backup and Sync.

Somehow the update from Google Drive to Google Backup and Sync disabled this and registering it again solved the problem.

Comment: This worked, but only after I restarted backup &sync

Answer (score 1):

I used this same dll registration to assist a backup and sync issue.

After registering the DLL and restarting Backup and Sync now I can finally see the status of the update and the top menus are no longer greyed out all the time as before.

regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\contextmenu64.dll"